# Regexp to normalise (pad with zeroes) IP addresses

Tags: regex, ip-address, replace

I have a copy of a log file I want to make easier to view/edit.
I use textpad to remove stuff I do not want and I can enter a regular expression as search term and use **\1.\2.\3.\4** in the target field for captured groups.
I would like to change all IP addresses which start each line from

```
[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

to

```
[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}
```

with padded leading zeros
How to do that in one go?

Example input:

```
10.2.123.4
110.12.23.40
123.123.123.123
1.2.3.4
```

example output

```
010.002.123.004
110.012.023.040
123.123.123.123
001.002.003.004
```

See my own answer for what works

Thanks for your input

Comment: You can start by replacing `\b(\d)\b` with `00\1` and `\b(\d\d)\b` with `0\1`. Don't do a replace all - it will replace other stray numbers

Comment: Thanks Amarghosh. that is more or less what I normally do. How does the \d\d on word boundary work? Because of the dot?

Comment: Because of the fact that `\d` is part of `\w`, while a dot or `$` is not. The `\b` matches any position between `\w` and anything but `\w`, so you can use it to delimit consecutive digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite the full, one liner you want, but it at least brings it down to two lines instead of your current 8.

Following the same formatting you used in your answer:

```
^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> 00\1.00\2.00\3.00\4

^0*([0-9]{3})\.0*([0-9]{3})\.0*([0-9]{3})\.0*([0-9]{3}) -> \1.\2.\3.\4
```

The way this works is that:

1. it pads all of the numbers so that there is at least 3 numbers in each section
2. it pulls out exactly 3 numbers from each section and ignores any leading '0's remaining

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I decided to do it in more than one go. I post it here for future reference or in case someone comes up with a single regex

Note there is a trailing space on each find and each replace

```
^([0-9]{1})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> 00\1.\2.\3.\4 
^([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> 0\1.\2.\3.\4 

^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{1})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> \1.00\2.\3.\4 
^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> \1.0\2.\3.\4 

^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{1})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> \1.\2.00\3.\4 
^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> \1.\2.0\3.\4 

^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{1}) -> \1.\2.\3.00\4 
^([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2}) -> \1.\2.\3.0\4
```

Textpad syntax:

```
^\([0-9]\{1\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> 00\1.\2.\3.\4 
^\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> 0\1.\2.\3.\4 

^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> \1.00\2.\3.\4 
^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> \1.0\2.\3.\4 

^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> \1.\2.00\3.\4 
^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,3\}\) -> \1.\2.0\3.\4 

^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1\}\) -> \1.\2.\3.00\4 
^\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{3\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\) -> \1.\2.\3.0\4
```

Comment: Why are you escaping all parentheses and curly braces? Is this textpad thing?

Comment: "in case someone comes up with a single regex" -> Nobody will, because this is impossible. And yes, I use that word rarely and if at all, then without exaggeration.

Comment: @Kobi: Agreed, the backslashes should be removed. They have nothing to do with the shown regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Spit on `"."`, pad, join. No regex needed. Regex would not provide any benefit, even.

JavaScript, for example:

```
var ip = "110.12.23.40";

ip = ip.split(".").map( function(i) {
  return ("00"+i).slice(-3);
}).join(".");

alert(ip);  // 110.012.023.040
```

Comment: Erm - where in my post or tags does it say I can run jQuery? Or is your post a textpad snippet I do not know about?
I am in an editor with 1.5 million lines and need to run a regex.
I can do this in JS just fine if I could run JS in my editor.

Comment: @mplungjan: Erm - where in my answer do I say that this code would be jQuery? It says JavaScript, and that's what it is. There are methods to manipulate text files outside of an editor, and I think this is one case where it would be beneficial to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the erm - just a little tired of what I see as unrelated answers to my questions at SO so far. I need a regex in my editor. I use JS daily. can also write a JAVA or REXX program that reads through the file and pads the ip addresses. But that is not what I want or need right now.
PS: Your "map" is not average JS, but JS 1.6. Very clever and useful in other contexts

Comment: @mplungjan: My JavaScript was to illustrate a point, only. I could have used another language. You cannot easily use regex for this since a) regex *finds*, it does not replace; b) finding the correct spots to insert zeros can be difficult in the context of a huge log file and c) this will always be a multi-step operation, to do it correctly it would require 8 search-and-replace steps (4 bytes separatetly, "0" and "00" prefixes separately). What I'm saying is this: Use a programming language to process your text file. Regex-find IPs, replace using something equivalent to my code.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but as I mentioned, I can replace captured strings. If the captured input is [0-9]{1} my replace is 00\1 if [0-9]{2} it is 0\1 and if [0-9]{3} it is \1
Since I can do it one at a time, I was sure someone could come up with a compound regex like this single replace ([0-9]{1})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3}) -> 00\1.\2.\3.\4

So I guess I can do it in 4 regex now.

Comment: @mplungjan: Yes, eight, as I said. You need to capture and replace these cases separately: `"x.*.*.*"`, `"xx.*.*.*"`, `"*.x.*.*"`, `"*.xx.*.*"`, `"*.*.x.*"`, `"*.*.xx.*"`, `"*.*.*.x"`, `"*.*.*.xx"`. Not replacing complete IP-address-like structures will leave you with leading zeros in dates, times and other data. It's not impossible to do in a text editor, but a lot more hassle than it's worth. (And as far as efficiency goes: This way you would need to go over the entire file eight times - but with a small helper program only once.)

Comment: It was actually not a huge thing, 8 times enter and I had the ^ making sure it was only the first part of the line.
It took less than what I spent on this question ;) Also I had to sort and remove crap requests something textpad is very good helping your eyes with and programming languages not...
Thanks for your input - At least I learned about map()